# How to count number of words spoken using any method (SR or otherwise)

Tags: nlp, speech-recognition, speech, counting

I am having some trouble getting pointers to how to perform what appears to be a deceptively easy task:

**Given an audio stream, how do you count the number of words that have been spoken, in real-time?**

I don't need to recognize what the words are, but rather just have an accurate counter on words that have been uttered. The counter doesn't have to be too accurate and could even consider utterances and other "grunts" like coughs.

It appears that all Speech Recognition systems depend on a pre-defined grammar to be provided before they can analyze the phonemes that are spoken to convert to known words with some degree of accuracy. But I don't care about the accuracy at all, but rather the rate of words being spoken.

What is important is that this runs in real time, and allow the system to provide alerts after a certain number of words have been spoken. The system will encourage a visual cue to pause, and then the speaker can continue.

I've looked at CMU Sphinx FAQ and found that the idea of "word spotting" is not yet supported. I don't really need a real time search of particular words, but it approximates more closely to what I am looking for. Looking for very small silences in the waveform seems to be a very crude way of doing this and probably not very accurate at all, but that's all I have right now.

Any pointers on algorithms, research papers or any other insights would be appreciated!

Comment: It's important to understand if you know the words which your users is supposed to speaker. If you do it's an easy task. If you don't the task is not easier than speech recognition itself.

Comment: And it actually better to describe the problem you are trying to solve not the solution you have in mind. Your solution might be wrong or too complex for the specific problem.

Comment: We are trying to create better public speakers, Nikolay. So what we are doing is working to see how many words are spoken before pauses are made - www.takethestage.info is the description. Does that help to describe the problem better?

Comment: Given your task you should better measure speaking rate by detecting syllables, not counting words. And there are quite some more speech rate detectors.

Comment: Can you provide some pointers to open source speech rate detectors in the answers below? That would be terrific!

Comment: Its more than 3 years since you asked this question (and I am now having similar need).. did u find anything on this front?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, I'll encourage you to ask the question here in the discussion instead https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/nlp/beta/discussions. Most probably the questions would be flagged as "asking for tool/fix recommendation" as it is now.